# React native need to render rounded shadow on rounded button

Tags: react-native, shadow, react-native-stylesheet

I need to render rounded shadow on rounded button. Shadow should be render like given in image but some how i am not able to render like that.

[image]

But it is not render properly and display like below.

[image]

It looks like below

[image]

Style will be like this

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle : {
    height: 60,
    width: 60, 
    marginRight: 15,
    shadowColor: "#4e4f72",
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 30,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 0,
      width: 0
    },
    borderRadius: 30,
    elevation: 30,
  },
})
```

> View style

```
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 15 }}>
    
       <Image style={styles.buttonStyle} source={require('../images/google.png')} />
    
       <Image style={styles.buttonStyle} source={require('../images/facebook.png')} />
    
       <Image style={{ height: 60, width: 60, }} source={require('../images/instagram.png')} />
    
    </View>
```

Comment: can you show us the code of the view where you applied the buttonStyle object?

Comment: @realarb question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to place your image inside a View. Remove the shadow styling from the image and place it to the View. In my case this is working.

```
  <View
    style={{
      height: 60,
      width: 60,
      marginRight: 15,
      shadowColor: '#4e4f72',
      shadowOpacity: 0.2,
      shadowRadius: 30,
      shadowOffset: {
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
      },
      borderRadius: 30,
      elevation: 30,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}
  >
    <Image style={{ height: 60, width: 60, borderRadius: 30 }} />
  </View>
```

Don't forget to add the require back to the Image component